# jQuery Masked Input - É possível recuperar a máscara atrelada ao campo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-masked-input

Estou usando [jQuery Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) com [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/). Quando um campo do formulário perde o foco, o plugin de validação mostra uma mensagem, mas isso não está acontecendo com os campos que são têm máscaras, talvez porque o evento blur acontece e verifica que o campo não está vazio, na verdade, o campo está preenchido com a máscara.

Então eu sobrescrevi o método [required](http://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method/) do plugin de validação para verificar as máscaras também, mas eu tenho que verificar a máscara. Como eu tenho máscaras diversas não posso hard code a máscara, eu teria que chamar um método no plugin que me retorna a máscara vinculada ao campo. Eu não encontrei a documentação do plugin e ninguém com o meu problema.

Alguém sabe se existe um método que me devolve a máscara vinculada ao campo?

Comment: Olhando o [código-fonte](https://raw.github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/1.3.1/dist/jquery.maskedinput.js) parece que o valor passado por parâmetro para a função `mask` não é armazenada em lugar algum.

Comment: Procurei um pouco e achei uma solução para meu problema que seria utilizar o método unmask e verificar se o valor sem a máscara é igual a vazio.

Comment: Ah, ok. Eu postei uma resposta parcial em todo caso. Mas é melhor você responder a você mesmo e aceitar a sua resposta como certa.

Comment: Ainda não implementei para ver se funciona, até mesmo porque eu só passava o valor, agora terei que passar o objeto todo. Vou olhar sua resposta, pode ser uma idéia.

Answer (score 1):

Olhando o [código-fonte](https://raw.github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/1.3.1/dist/jquery.maskedinput.js) parece que o valor passado por parâmetro para a função `mask` não é armazenada em lugar algum.

O que é possível fazer inspecionando o código é ver se o campo possui uma máscara acessando o atributo `data` chamado `rawMaskFn`:

```js
$(seletor).data('rawMaskFn')
```

Em minha experiência, esse plugin é muito limitado em funcionalidade.

Comment: O que seria o atributo data? O plugin adiciona esse atributo ao meu input? E e esse valor rawMaskFn? Você usa algum outro plugin para máscaras?

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi A função [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) do jQuery permite adicionar e remover atributos. E, sim, o plugin adiciona esse atributo dentro da função `mask()` e o retira na função `unmask()`. Isso pode servir como uma *flag* para indicar se o campo tem ou não uma máscara, mas não permite recuperar a máscara em si.

Comment: Eu poderia usar attr para adicionar atributos também, certo? Vale uma pergunta pedir as diferenças entre eles? E você recomenda algum plugin para utilizar máscaras?

Comment: Lendo a documentação vi que existem dois métodos data. Lerei depois com mais calma para ver as diferenças entre os três.